# Unwanted environment variables in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, environment-variables

I have a Makefile which conditionally defines the compiler like so:

```
CC?=$(SOMETHING)
```

This is necessary because the file is sometimes called by a script which defines a different compiler.
This used to work fine, but on my new Linux installation, when I run make I find that CC has already been defined somewhere, as 'cc', which I don't want.
It's not in my shell environment. It's like make has it's own private environment. Where is it coming from, and how can I get rid of it (without changing the Makefile)?

Comment: `cc` is the default value for `CC` in GNU make: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html (on the same page it also mentions the possiblity of using `-R` to get rid of these defaults)

Comment: ```COMPILER?=$(SOMETHING)``` then ```CC=$(COMPILER)```

Comment: Well that explains it. Now the question is why it ever worked in the first place...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cc` is the default/implicit value for `CC` in GNU Make, see gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html (thanks Paul R)

One way to circumvent it is by having a variable in the middle (thanks Matheus):

```
COMPILER?=$(SOMETHING)
CC=$(COMPILER)
```

It is also possible to suppress all implicit variables by invoking make like `make --no-builtin-variables`, though this suppresses all implicit rules as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you use GNU make and you don't want the default value of `CC` to apply you can use the `origin` function and the `ifeq` conditional to get rid of it:

```
ifeq ($(origin CC),default)
CC = $(SOMETHING)
else
CC ?= $(SOMETHING)
endif
```

See [*The origin Function* section of the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Origin-Function) for a complete explanation.